# Docker refusing to run bash

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker setup:

python27.Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN mkdir /src
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash libmysqlclient-dev python-pip build-essential && pip install virtualenv
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /src
CMD source /src/env/bin/activate && python /src/manage.py runserver
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# some code here...
# some code here...
# some code here...

exec "$@"
```

Whenever I try to run my docker container I get `python27 | /bin/sh: 1: source: not found`.

I understand that the error comes from the fact that the command is run with `sh` instead of `bash`, but I can't understand why is that happening, given the fact that I have the correct shebang at the top of my entrypoint.

Any ideas why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your shebang has bash?

Comment: @johnharris85 Yes, I'm installing it in the 4th line in my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for CMD you're using the *shell form* that uses /bin/sh, and the /src/env/bin/activate likely contains a "source" command, which isn't available on POSIX /bin/sh (the equivalent builtin would be just `.`).

You must use the *exec form* for CMD using brackets:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /src/env/bin/activate && python /src/manage.py runserver"]
```

More details in:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Yes, that work. But I still can't understand why is this happening. I mean, the entrypoint get's executed with the command (as arguments) of the CMD. The entrypoint executes `exec '$@'`, which is basically `exec source ..... && python ....`, and all that inside bash. So why is the `source` part failing?

Comment: See the last part of the last link of my response, on the result of the multiple different ENTRYPOINT / CMD combinations.  In your case, it would be:
`/entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c source ...`

Comment: PD: By `exec form` they mean using the exec*() system calls and not the **exec** builtin shell command.